# Hyper-V - Unable to delete multiple Checkpoints

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

We have two Hyper-V servers running on Windows Server 2016. One is one main server, the other one is the replica server where the main one replicates to.

We took down the replica server for maintenance and Hyper-V was unable to replicate to it and we think that due to this, one of the VM's wasn't ahppy and created a number of checkpoints (it may or may not be realted to this).

Regardless of the cause, one of the VM's on the main server now has 3 checkpoints which is creating a storage issue for us.

There is no option to delete the checkpoints and if I click delete on any of them, I get the error:

```
Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). Checkpoint ID AF4E3BE9-9A1A-4E34-9F7D-F6F7A84531BF.
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree: 'Catastrophic failure'('0x8000FFFF').
```

No matter what I do, I cannot delete them. I scheduled maintenance for the VM and powered it down thinking that it could be because it was started, same issue.

I tried changing the storage file to the newer file created but because it was an avhxd it wouldn't start because it needs the vhdx file to do so.

I read that you needed to do it via PowerShell, but I get the same error using that.

We're now running into a problem whereby we'll run out of storage space because the original VM is 600GB in size and while we had plenty of space, it's now created a number of checkpoints also reaching the same size.

So...

What can I do to resolve this?

One option I can think of is to export the VM, delete everything and re-import the exported VM and that should fix it?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

PowerShell output below.

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-VMSnapshot -VMName "My VM Name" -ComputerName SERVERNAME | Remove-VMSnapshot
    Remove-VMSnapshot : 'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint.
    Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF).
    Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree.
    'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint. (Virtual machine ID 33E39D27-D0DB-4F89-A080-6A50E112B941)
    Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). Checkpoint ID 

AF4E3BE9-9A1A-4E34-9F7D-F6F7A84531BF.
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree: 'Catastrophic failure'('0x8000FFFF').
At line:1 char:67
+ ...  -VMName "My VM Name" -ComputerName SERVERNAME | Remove-VMSnapshot
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-VMSnapshot], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVMSnapshot

Remove-VMSnapshot : 'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint.
Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF).
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree.
'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint. (Virtual machine ID 33E39D27-D0DB-4F89-A080-6A50E112B941)
Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). Checkpoint ID CE0939F2-4E67-4833-905B-C4D8C62A57D8.
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree: 'Catastrophic failure'('0x8000FFFF').
At line:1 char:67
+ ...  -VMName "My VM Name" -ComputerName SERVERNAME | Remove-VMSnapshot
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-VMSnapshot], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVMSnapshot

Remove-VMSnapshot : 'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint.
Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF).
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree.
'My VM Name' failed to remove checkpoint. (Virtual machine ID 33E39D27-D0DB-4F89-A080-6A50E112B941)
Cannot delete checkpoint: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). Checkpoint ID 5C2D8EA1-8DEA-4087-B40D-CC4E99216ECF.
Virtual machine failed to generate VHD tree: 'Catastrophic failure'('0x8000FFFF').
At line:1 char:67
+ ...  -VMName "My VM Name" -ComputerName SERVERNAME | Remove-VMSnapshot
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-VMSnapshot], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVMSnapshot

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Have you tried the export yet? That would be my next step.

Comment: @EricSiron That looks like my only option now and what I've got planned at a suitable time. Thanks.